# Ubuntu on HP X2 1012 - Install problems

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, hp, tablet

having found reports that ubuntu runs well on the brandnew HP Elite X2 1012 tablet, I wanted to install it as a **parallel boot option**.
I used the Windows 10 Disk Manager to shrink the Win partition and freed 60 GB, which should be sufficient for a first attempt.
I downloaded then the Ubuntu ISO Image 15.10 AMD64 - used various sources - and installed it on USB stick AND on DVD. With both in several variations booting as into the Live environment as in the install mode failed - the system loading got stuck after a minute or so, leaving me with the ubuntu logo and some frozen red/white dots on the screen (and I did wait for 15 minutes or so!)

Fallback scenario: use the last stable release and upgrade afterwards. I d/l the 14.4 ISO Image and installed it on the USB stick. Live boot works fine, and booting into install mode does, too. The free space on /dev/sda can be seen too; **HOWEVER**, the ubuntu installer does **NOT** recognize the existing Win 10 installation - so I chicked out and cancelled the installation. 
Having invested considerable time in optimizing the Win10 I do not want to loose it ...

Anyone having an idea why the ubuntu install process does not recon the installed Win10? And is there a "best practice" model out there to follow?

Would be grateful for a hint -

sincerely, cw

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Probably not the best way to make it work, but for me it did the job. Try it at your own risk:

- Resize Windows partition - I freed 60 GB and inserted a 128 GB micro SD as backup medium. Made a Backup of the Win installation there.
- Ubuntu image 16.04 - ISO : download and use Universal USB Installer to get it on a USB-Stick
- Press ESC while starting the 1012. Boot options: deactivate Fastboot. Save and reboot.  Boot to Windows: Energy options - deactivate Fastboot here, too.
- Boot from USB-Stick: ESC - Boot menu - Device in UEFI (!)-Mode
- Start Live-Mode to test whether or not you like it
- start Install
- When asked for partitioning: choose "something else" and use the free space for 8 GB Swap and rest /. Bootloader: goes to sda
- finish normal install, Shutdown -h
- boot from USB-Stick, start Live-system
- open terminal and enter:
  sudo -s

  *REMARK:* Object-Library for python:

  apt-get install python-gobject

  *REMARK:* add repository for boot-repair:

  add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
  sudo apt-get update

  *REMARK:* install boot-repair:

  sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
  boot-repair

Reboot after finishing should bring up the GRUB loader and the menu. The "Fast Boot" options in Bios and Windows can be reactivated afterwars (makes not much difference though)